# How to provide symbols for obfuscated Flutter Android app bundles

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, obfuscation

I have a Flutter app targeting Android. I used to build app bundle using this command:

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

I would then zip and upload native debug symbols from `build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` folder.

I am trying to use obfuscation, so I have switched to this command:

```
flutter build appbundle --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./build/symbols
```

This works and it creates three files in my "build/symbols" folder:

- app.android-arm.symbols
- app.android-arm64.symbols
- app.android-x64.symbols

When I zip these three files into `symbols.zip` file and use `upload native debug symbols` to the Play Store, they are rejected with this error:

> The native debug symbols contain an unexpected file:
> app.android-x64.symbols.
> app.android-arm64.symbols.
> app.android-arm.symbols.

I can still upload symbols from `build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` as before.

Can someone explain what is the difference between these two sets of symbol files and what should I use in my store submission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been researching these topic and I got the difference.

There are 2 types of obfuscation in a flutter app:

1. native libraries (java, kotlin, etc.) code
2. dart libraries (all your dart code)

When you upload `build\app\intermediates\merged_native_libs\release\out\lib` to the play console, it is used to de-obfuscate the native libraries.
This zip is also called as native debug symbols.

So when a crash occurs by the native code, these symbols will be used to de-obfuscate the `Stack-trace` by the Play console.

Now on the other hand, `*.symbols` files created by the flutter command(in your case files in `build/symbols` folder) are debug symbols to de-obfuscate dart code.

They will be used to de-obfuscate `Stack-trace` related to a dart-code crash. You'll see these crashes in something like `Firebase Crashlytics`.

To upload these symbols to Firebase use the following command:

```bash
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app=APP_ID PATH/TO/symbols
```

In your case `PATH/TO/symbols` will be `build/symbols`